# Stacking labels and controls "crisscrossed" when belonging to different rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in which the control labels appear on top of them instead of to one of their sides, like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label for="TextControl">Text control</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label for="NumericControl">Numeric control</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input label="TextControl" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input label="NumericControl" type="number" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine, since at full screen it shows something like:

```
Text control    Numeric control
| tcontrol |    |  ncontrol   |
```

But when I resize to something smaller, the labels get stacked one after the other, followed by the controls:

```
Text control    
Numeric control
| tcontrol |
|  ncontrol   |
```

I would like it to look "crisscrossed": label followed by its corresponding control:

```
Text control
| tcontrol |    
Numeric control
|  ncontrol   |
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Make it in a different way. Maybe try using CSS grid.

Comment: I'd be able to make this in a little bit, if you don't mind waiting.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/ek8dg5wb/)?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan that could work. Thanks.